# Using strtok() to break a line with multiple delimiters in C

Tags: c, parsing, strtok

So I'm currently trying to write a program which should be able to take MIPS assembly language, and translate some parts to the binary representation. I'm getting lines in this format:

```
add   $s0, $t0, $s2;
```

I'm trying to use strtok to break up the separate tokens, but all I've been able to accomplish so far is separate out the instruction label. I can read in the line and get the

```
add
```

all by itself, but the rest of the string gets messed up and it's becomes garbage. I'm currently only delimiting using

```
"   "
```

as delimiter, but as you can see the delimiter changes further down the line. How can I tokenize the string, and receive each of the separate tokens so I can do the translation?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example:

Answer (score 2):

Specify a delimiter as a single space. After first call to strtok, on next calls set NULL as a first strtok's argument. [man strtok](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strtok) should be helpful.